# Testing HTTP with mockbackends

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm working on building out tests for my services in Angular 2.  Building out the mock backends is proving to be a real trial.  I have been able to test the services with it making actual HTTP requests successfully but I would like to keep these segregated from the third part.

I've combed through the two main articles I have been able to find ([first](https://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/testing-angular-2-apps-routeroutlet-and-http/), [second](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-unit-testing-with-jasmine-defe20421584#.4ld73ae8c)) as well as the [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

When I was making successful http requests to actual third party services, I had to use `done();` to ensure that the test waited for the request to complete.  It seems that the case is the same here.  If I do not use it, the test will be a success even with `expect(1).toBe(2);`.  When I do use it, it times out waiting for the call to complete.  Error:

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Here's my code:

```
import {
    it,
    inject,
    describe,
    beforeEachProviders,
    expect,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

import { AccountService } from './../../source/scripts/services/account.service';
import { provide } from '@angular/core';

describe('AccountService', () => {
    // let service;

    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        AccountService,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        MockBackend,
        provide(Http, {
            deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
            useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
            },
        }),
    ]);

    beforeEach(<any>inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) => {
        const baseResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: 'got response' }));
        backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(baseResponse));
    }));

    // We use 'done' for async callbacks (http calls)    
    it('should return mocked response', (done) => {

        inject([AccountService], (testService: AccountService) => {
            testService.getUsers().subscribe((res: Response) => {
                expect(res.text()).toBe('got response');
                expect(1).toBe(2);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How do I properly test http calls with a mockbackend?  I suspect that either the links I referenced above are out of date or they didn't confirm that the test was actually testing rather than just giving false positives without the async of `done();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Only the async `done` is not appropriate here because `inject` has to replace this anonymous callback. So here is the fixed version:

```
it('should return mocked response', inject([AccountService], (testService: AccountService) => {
  testService.getUsers().subscribe((res: Response) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('got response');
    expect(1).toBe(2);
  });
}));
```

Another problem is missing `beforeEach` import:

```
import {
    it,
    inject,
    describe,
    beforeEach, // <-- this one was missing
    beforeEachProviders,
    expect,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

So there was a Jasmine's `beforeEach` instance which doesn't allow to use `inject`.

Comment: Answered by the blog author himself!  Changing my assertion to match what you have above gives a different error.  I think it's a problem with how it's parsing it?  It happened when I tried to inject the service into the `beforeEach` section as well.  The trace is something like this:
`_instantiateProvider@C:/sites/Scratch/prototype_ui/config/karma-test-shim.js:18060:38 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:626:0`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, theres no `beforeEach` in imports as well. I'll update the answer :)

Comment: Hmm, that is odd, you're right.  I'm using it here and in all my other tests and it hasn't ever said anything about there not being a beforeEach from imports.

Comment: It will work with Jasmine's `beforeEach` until you want to use `inject` there.

Comment: Ohh, that's why I have to declare `<any>` before injecting, it's using the wrong beforeEach.  That makes sense but I'm still getting the same error after adding `beforeEach` and removing the `<any>`.

Comment: I've just copied your code and it now works fine. Have you succeed with any other tests before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114279/discussion-between-wojciech-kwiatek-and-aarmora).

Comment: To clarify for anyone later looking at this question.  I am using an additional parameter in my service that was causing the `_instantiateProvider` error.  Removing that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Shouldn't the `inject` be wrapped with `async` like `async(inject(...))` so the test waits for the async operation to be completed? I think it depends on the Angular2 version because this async handling has changed a lot recently.

Comment: This one was tested with Angular 2 rc.1 and works just fine. Maybe it will change but for now I had to use `async(inject(...))` only in `beforeEach`. Do you have a link to Angular discussion about it?